# Why does ClickOnce stops publishing the Setup.exe?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

[image]

It seems if i delete setup.exe, VisualStudio/ClickOnce will never create it again.

I did rebuild, clean solution, Updated the Assembly Version and File Version, deleted the certificates, created new ones. I don't know what else to do.

**How can i make VisualStudio/ClickOnce publish setup.exe again?**

Comment: Did you "deploy" (which is more than just a "(re)build")?

Comment: I did Publish just like i did at 3:27 PM, the time u see in the picture. The only thing that's getting updated is the Application Files and .aplication. , but setup.exe remains created at the same time, and if i delete it it will never be created again :-S. PS:I don't know what u mean by deploy.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Publish". Strange, I renamed my setup.exe and it does get recreated so I have both the renamed old version and the new one (also using VS2015).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like i found the problem: 
[image]

Unchecking the "Create setup program to install prequisite components" makes VisualStudio/ClickOnce stop creating the setup.exe file.

If your software is running offline like mine did, to fix it check the Create, and tick the Download from same location as my application, and setup.exe will be created again.